# I had a sparse matrix, when I open it in R, all elements which should be 0 are dots like ' . ', how can I convert it this dot to number 0?

Tags: r, matrix

I had a sparse matrix, when I open it in R, all elements which should be 0 are dots like ' . ', how can I convert it this dot to number 0? That is converting it to numeric matrix that can be used in following calculation.

I know a command to convert all the element which is NA to 0: that is

```
Mydata[is.na(Mydata)]<-0
```

But I do not know how to convert dot to 0.

Comment: If it's sparse then they are not "dots". That just the way the print function displays them in standard n x m format. If you make them actually 0's then you loose the advantages of having the matrix be sparse.

Answer (score 3):

If your matrix is sparse you can convert it to a regular matrix using `as.matrix`

For example,

```
m <- Matrix:::Matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, sparse = TRUE)

as.matrix(m)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As.matrix works on the subset of my matrix. However, since the sparse matrix is really large, when I apply it on the whole matrix, it generated the error: "Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c, line 136"

Comment: What is the dimensions of your matrix?

Comment: Sorry it still not working, it just works on my subset of my matrix. The dimension is :72462*28279, we can reduce the column number but better not reduce the row number

Comment: ok, that's quite a big vector (length 2049152898). Maybe something in `bigmemory` can help

Answer (score 2):

That's just the way sparse matrices from the Matrix package work. The entries are assumed to be zero but they are not actually explicitly stored as zeros in the internal representation. Only the non-zero entries get stored. That's where the "sparse-ness" comes in. If you extract a particular element from the sparse matrix it comes out as a zero.

```
>  require(Matrix)
Loading required package: Matrix

Attaching package: ‘Matrix’

The following object is masked from ‘package:SparseM’:

    det

> ?Matrix
> M <- Matrix(0, 3, 2)
> M
3 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] . .
[2,] . .
[3,] . .
> M[1,1]
[1] 0
```

(Your follow-on question about a SAS document really makes no sense. The only way to add meaning to this discussion would be to post *more* code and details.)

Answer (score 0):

Usually I try to deal with this at import so that I don't have a problem with it later. Most of the import commands have something that identifies NA strings (frequently `na.strings`).

```
d <- read.csv("~/path/to/your/file.csv", na.strings = ".")
```

Then your original presumption works well:

```
d[is.na(d)] <- 0
```

You also won't have to concern yourself with conversion from character to numeric.

Comment: But what I have is sas document, I directly read it into R, it is not excel file existed in my directory path

Comment: And when I try to read out the sparse matrix to my directory path, it generated an error: "Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("dgCMatrix", package = "Matrix")" to a data.frame"

Comment: The command I use is:write.csv(markTermDocument,"markTermDocument.csv")

Comment: `write.csv` has the argument, `na`. Use the argument `write.csv(...,na = ".")`